# Incremental update in sqoop

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, sqoop

Hi I loaded a data from mysql to hdfs via sqoop connector. Now what if row between the existing data get updated, is there any query to update the data value of existing row  in sqoop. I am aware of the incremental update?Will in incremental update also update the existing row? I am new to sqoop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should use the `lastmodified` mode when you perform your incremental imports. According to the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports):

> An alternate table update strategy supported by Sqoop is called
>   lastmodified mode. You should use this when rows of the source table
>   may be updated, and each such update will set the value of a
>   last-modified column to the current timestamp. Rows where the check
>   column holds a timestamp more recent than the timestamp specified with
>   --last-value are imported.
>
> At the end of an incremental import, the value which should be
>   specified as --last-value for a subsequent import is printed to the
>   screen. When running a subsequent import, you should specify
>   --last-value in this way to ensure you import only the new or updated data. This is handled automatically by creating an incremental import
>   as a saved job, which is the preferred mechanism for performing a
>   recurring incremental import. See the section on saved jobs later in
>   this document for more information.

Bear in mind that this mode requires a column which holds a date value (such as `date`, `time`, `datetime` and `timestamp`).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38458064/2026277) shows an alternative importing strategy for existing values using `merge-key`.